# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll, whenever try to run the web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, connection-string

Getting this error when trying to run the page. I guess the issue is with the connection string. But couldn't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Connection string is as follows:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Lijo\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Employee\\Employee\\App_Data\\Employee.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

When the connection opens, there the error occurs.

```
protected void BindData()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable FromTable = new DataTable();
    conn.Open();        //<-- At this point the error is throwing
    string cmdstr = "Select * from tblLeaves";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(ds);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    FromTable = ds.Tables[0];
    if (FromTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        gvEmployeeDetails.DataSource = FromTable;
        gvEmployeeDetails.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        FromTable.Rows.Add(FromTable.NewRow());
        gvEmployeeDetails.DataSource = FromTable;
        gvEmployeeDetails.DataBind();
        int TotalColumns = gvEmployeeDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
        gvEmployeeDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
        gvEmployeeDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        gvEmployeeDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = TotalColumns;
        gvEmployeeDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No records Found";
    }
    ds.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: from the title `An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'`

Comment: Please edit your post with the complete exception

Comment: Without seeing the full exception, we can't help much. The only thing I see that could pose and issue is you need to put a '@' before your connection string, but this should be caught by IntelliSense and cause your build to fail. Please give us more info as the SqlException is very, very broad.

Comment: What is the state of your connection before you execute that line?